# Need to match some pattern exclude specific characters

Tags: regex

Need regular expression to match xxxx.xxxx pattern but not include the sentence having $"xxxx.xxxx"

Example

```
"$xxxx.xxxxx"
aaaa.aaaaaa
bbbb.bbbbb
"$gggg.hhhh"
```

My Rex

```
(\w+\.\w+)[^"]
```

Actual Result

```
xxxx.xxxx
aaaa.aaaaaa
bbbb.bbbbb
gggg.hhh
```

Expected Result

```
aaaa.aaaaaa
bbbb.bbbbb
```

Comment: Are you using a programming language?

Comment: This works ->  \b(\w+\.\w+)(?!")\b   but if any better solution , please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `$` at the end of the regex. What's happening is that your regex group, `(\w+\.\w+)`, is matching all but the last letter, then `[^"]` matches the last letter. Adding `$` (end of string) forces the last character to match `[^"]`, which should remove your unwanted matches.